# How to post comment on photo using graph api in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:txtComment.text, @"message", nil];
NSString *strPicId = [[Appdel.arrFacebookImages objectAtIndex:Appdel.getIndex] valueForKey:@"id"];
NSString *strPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/comments",strPicId];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:strPath parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result1, NSError *error)
 {
     if(!error)
     {
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);
     }
 }];
```

but when it runs, it giving me error like below,

```
   ERROR:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xb36dd80 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_stream";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
```

I have successfully logged in and I am also getting photo albums, photos, comments, but I can't post any comment on any photo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing publish permission in your access token.

You can get it with:

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                       defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                          allowLoginUI:YES
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen && !error) {
            // Publish the comment (your code inside) if permission was granted
            [self publishComment];
        }
    }];
```

That was the code from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/